# How to create these three threads in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, executorservice, execution, java-threads

I am new to threads, and I don't know much about them, however I am struggling with creating them mainly.

I created a GUI program that repeatedly sorts a randomly generated array of ints using either selection sort, insertion sort, or merge sort. Each sort operates on a list whose size is raised by a power of 2. Upon completion of each sort, the number of elements sorted and the number of milliseconds it took is displayed.

I have 3 classes already done, they are Merge, selection, and insertion.

My Merge sort is working correctly, however I am still having trouble with the selection and insertion. I'm not sure if my 'if' and 'else' statements are incorrect, or if the threads themselves are wrong, but I am struggling with them.

Here's what I have in my Main class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Sorter extends JFrame
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int WIDTH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

public static final String SELECTION_SORT_TEXT = "Selection Sort";
public static final String INSERTION_SORT_TEXT = "Insertion Sort";
public static final String MERGE_SORT_TEXT = "Merge Sort";

private JComboBox sortingAlgorithms;
private JTextArea display;
private JButton sortButton;
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel loadingIcon;
private JLabel sort;
private String[] options = {SELECTION_SORT_TEXT, INSERTION_SORT_TEXT, MERGE_SORT_TEXT};

public Sorter()
{
    setTitle("Sorter");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createContents();
    setVisible(true);
}
private void createContents()
{
    //TODO: Implement

    this.panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    this.display = new JTextArea();
    this.loadingIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("loading.gif"));
    this.sort = new JLabel("Sorting Algorithm");
    this.sortButton = new JButton("Sort");
    this.sortingAlgorithms = new JComboBox<>(options);
    loadingIcon.setSize(25,25);

    display.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    panel.add(sort);
    panel.add(sortingAlgorithms);
    panel.add(sortButton);
    panel.add(loadingIcon);

    sortButton.addActionListener(new SortButtonListener());

    loadingIcon.setVisible(false);
    display.setEnabled(false);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private class SortButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private int[] arr;
    private SortRunnable sr;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        sr.run();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        //TODO: Finish Implementation
        if(e.getSource() == sortButton)
        {
            sortingAlgorithms.setEnabled(false);
            sortButton.setEnabled(false);
            loadingIcon.setVisible(true);
            display.setText("N\t\tRuntime (ms)");             
        }
        arr = new int [2000];
        for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            arr = new int [(int) Math.pow(2, i) * 1000];
            fillArr();
            sr = new SortRunnable((String) sortingAlgorithms.getSelectedItem(), arr, Sorter.this);
            es.execute(sr);
        }
        Thread sortContext = new Thread(new SortRunnable((String) 
        sortingAlgorithms.getSelectedItem(), arr, Sorter.this));
        sortContext.start();
        es.shutdown();
    }
    /*
    These values are powers of 2 from 0 to 8, times 1000.
     */
    private void fillArr()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
/*
The displayResult method is responsible for adding the provided sort runtime information to
the display. It should also check to see if the final sort runtime information is present. If so,
it should hide the loading gif and enable the JComboBox and sort button.
 */
public synchronized void displayResult(int n, long runtime)
{
    //TODO: Implement
    display.append("\n" + n + "\t\t" + runtime);
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    new Sorter();
 }
}
```

I am not too concerned with what's above. I am more concerned on how to create my thread in my SortRunnable class which these threads are created. Here is what is expected from this class.

This class contains the code used to time and execute the selected sort.

• You can find the difference between calls to System.currentTimeMillis() at the start end end of the sort to get its runtime.

• Call "Thread.yield()" in the Runnable before the search is executed to ensure that the GUI thread has the priority required to update its display as needed.

• When the sort has finished, the display should be updated in the GUI thread. This can be accomplished by calling the "displayResult" method on the Sorter reference. This call should occur within the Runnable object's run method, passed as an argument to SwingUtilities invokeLater method, as in:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
 {
 @Override
 public void run() 
 {
   //call Sorter's displayResult method here
 }
 });
```

Here is my code in there that I need help in.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SortRunnable implements Runnable
{

    private String sortingAlgorithm;
    private int[] arr;
    private Sorter sorter;

    public SortRunnable(String sortingAlgorithm, int[] arr, Sorter sorter)
    {
        this.sortingAlgorithm = sortingAlgorithm;
        this.arr = arr;
        this.sorter = sorter;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.yield();
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.MERGE_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            MergeSort.mergeSort(arr);
        }
        Thread.yield();
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.SELECTION_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            SelectionSort.sort(arr);
        }
        Thread.yield();
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.INSERTION_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            InsertionSort.sort(arr);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Thread.yield();
                sorter.displayResult(arr.length, System.currentTimeMillis());
            //call Sorter's displayResult method here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I just need help with the Insertion and Selection thread. Thank you! If you would like their individual classes so you can see what's inside of them let me know.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have three classes that I didn't put on here, but they are the MergeSort, InsertionSort and SelectionSort. They do all the sorting. Yeah how do I make them each individually as threads.

Comment: Your title needs rewriting to show **how this Question is distinct** from the [29 million posts on Stack Overflow related to Java & threads](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&source=hp&ei=S2m2XLfNH6e40PEP9ZOE0AQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+thread&btnK=Google+Search&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+thread&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4675.10095..10285...2.0..0.106.2820.35j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0j0i10.FnGhR9j1KXc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution on creating these threads go as following:

In the sortRunnable class:

```
public void run()
    {
        long store = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.MERGE_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            MergeSort.mergeSort(arr);
        }
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.SELECTION_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            SelectionSort.sort(arr);
        }
        if(sortingAlgorithm.equals(sorter.INSERTION_SORT_TEXT))
        {
            InsertionSort.sort(arr);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                sorter.displayResult(arr.length, System.currentTimeMillis()-store);
            //call Sorter's displayResult method here
            }
        });
    }
```

That's where I created my threads.

On my other class, I put them in as following:

```
private class SortButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private int[] arr;
    private SortRunnable sr;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        //TODO: Finish Implementation
        if(e.getSource() == sortButton)
        {
            sortingAlgorithms.setEnabled(false);
            sortButton.setEnabled(false);
            loadingIcon.setVisible(true);
            display.setText("N\t\tRuntime (ms)");
        }
        arr = new int [2000];
        for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            arr = new int [(int) Math.pow(2, i) * 1000];
            fillArr();
            sr = new SortRunnable((String) sortingAlgorithms.getSelectedItem(), arr, Sorter.this);
            es.execute(sr);
        }
        es.shutdown();
    }
    private void fillArr()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Which the other methods was asked to do, but that's where I put in my threads.

Answer (score 1):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` places the request into in the Swing's event queue to be processed "at some point in the future".  The `Runnable` is dequeued and executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, meaning your sort is running in the same thread as the UI and will block it until it has completed.

Now, here is where things get really complicated.  Swing is NOT thread safe (meaning you shouldn't update the UI from outside of the Event Dispatching Thread context)and is single threaded, meaning any long running or blocking operations will prevent the UI from been updated.

The "long" answer is, use a `SwingWorker`, which is designed for this job.  However, you can continue using your code, but it's a little more messy.

You need to capture some more details, like when the sort was started and when the sort ended.  You then need to calculate the difference between these two points in time as milliseconds.

There are lots of ways you "might" do this, but since Java now sports a nice new date/time API, you might as well start making use of it.

This information is then passed back to the UI, maybe something like...

```
public class SortRunnable implements Runnable
{

    private String sortingAlgorithm;
    private int[] arr;
    private Sorter sorter;

    public SortRunnable(String sortingAlgorithm, int[] arr, Sorter sorter)
    {
        this.sortingAlgorithm = sortingAlgorithm;
        this.arr = arr;
        this.sorter = sorter;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        MergeSort.mergeSort(arr);
        LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        long diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startTime, endTime)
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                sorter.displayResult(arr.length, diff);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Okay, the next problem, is you're not making use of the `ExecutorService`.

First, it really should be an instance field, as you don't need to keep creating more instances of it.

Second, your logic is all over the place, basically you want to...

1. Create an instance of the `Sorter`
2. Fill the array
3. Create an instance of `SortRunnable`
4. Submit `SortRunnable` to the `ExecutorService` so it can be executed...

Maybe something more like...

```
private ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    fillArr();
    Sorter sorter = null;
    String algorthim = null;
    if(e.getSource() == options[0])
    {
        // create the instance of Sorter to be used...
        sorter = ...
        algorthim = ...
    }
    if(e.getSource() == options[1])
    {
        // create the instance of Sorter to be used...
        sorter = ...
        algorthim = ...
    }
    if(e.getSource() == options[2])
    {
        // create the instance of Sorter to be used...
        sorter = ...
        algorthim = ...
    }
    if (sorter != null) {
        SortRunnable sr = new SortRunnable(algorthim, arr, sorter)
        es.submit(sr);
    }
```

Comment: Alright, sounds reasonable, um where did the endDate and startDate come from? did you mean endTime and startTime?

Comment: @AdanVivero Whoops, copy and pasting from multiple sources :P

Comment: Alright, also, I have the algorithm in a different class. I just don't know how to bring it over to my e.getSource. Also I have a sort button that is a JComboBox that has the three sort methods inside of it. Do you still recommend to have each of them have their own e.getsource? And what do I have it set eqaul to?

Comment: *"I have the algorithm in a different class"* - Assuming that their within the same class path when built and run, simply create a new instance when you need to. *"Do you still recommend to have each of them have their own e.getsource?"* - For simplicity, probably, but if I was doing it, I would wrap the instance of `Sorter` and it's name into a class and use a custom cell renderer to render the text, that way when the `JComboBox`'s `ActionListener` is triggered, I'd just have to get a reference to the wrapper class, extract the details and pass them to the `SortRunnable`, but that's me

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I have the Merge thread working. I updated my code up above and everything, I am just struggling with my Insertion and Selection sort threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread sortContext = new Thread(new SortRunnable(*whatever args you need*));
sortContext.start();
```

should do the trick unless you try to update the ui from the new thread.

Comment: Just one question, where exactly do I put this in? Like which class?

Comment: The OP is already using a `ExecutorService`, `ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`, all be it poorly

Comment: wherever you want to initiate one of your three sorts.  I see you have a listener on a 'sort button'  perhaps in that class somewhere in the method thats called when the event is fired

Comment: an ExecutorService is used for scheduling concurrent work on a single thread or thread pool.   if this is what you are after than your question should be revised

Comment: Okay, but my question was where do I place it? which class? is it my Sorter class? or SortRunnable?

Comment: SortButtonListener, however, that class already contains the facility to run the sorting work concurrently.   the only thing i see missing is a way to pass in an instance of SortRunnable for it to execute.

Comment: What do you mean by instance? I don't know what that means?

Comment: also, it loos tike someone has been trying to experiment with using the ExecutorService.   One way to start a new task using that is es.execute(new SortRunnable(...));

Comment: calling new SortRunnable() creates an instance

Comment: Alright, and why do I need that? Sorry I know I'm asking a lot of questions, but I am just trying to nail this down and understand it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html  I think you'll want to have a firm grasp on terminology and basic object use before you try to wrap your head around parallel execution contexts.  Please start with the link above

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I have the Merge thread working. I updated my code up above and everything, I am just struggling with my Insertion and Selection sort threads.